# Python regex curly brackets multiline

Tags: python, regex, multiline, brackets

I'm writing in python and let's say I have a file looking like this:

```
aaa 

aaa "word" --sdsdrrr2 --sds {

test test 
}

aaa "word2" --sdsdd sdsd {

    fffsd
    ssss
}

aaa "word3" -sdksdld sdsd

{

    sdsdd
    sdsddd
    sdsdddd }
```

now I want to parse output for "word2" including prefix and suffix, so output will be:

```
aaa "word2" --sdsdd sdsd {

    fffsd
    ssss
}
```

tried the following code:

```
f = open('/tmp/testt2')

for res in re.findall('aaa "word2" (.*?)}', f.read(), re.S):
    print res
```

only got some of the matches without the beginning and the ending curly.

Please note:

- Number of lines between the curly brackets is unknown.
- Regex is a must
- Curly brackets positions are also unknown (can be spaced or not, new line or not etc) like in the example given above.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: If you copy pasted that regex you are missing the opening `{`. Plus you need [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

Comment: I am not sure but if  you need the whole value, why use a capturing group? Use `aaa "word2" .*?}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
^(?=.*"word2") # ^ - start of the line with pos. lookahead
[^{]+        # anything not a {
{[^}]+}      # followed by {, anything in between and a closing }
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gE7uF3/1) as well as [**a working fiddle on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/5bziPO).

Comment: works for word2/3, but if I want "word" it returns everything.

Comment: @NoamD: Put double quotes around the word.

Comment: `^(?=.* "word")
[^{]+
{[^}]+}` I think this is enough.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick for me, 
full code if anyone needs:



    regex = re.compile(r'^(?=.*"%s")[^{]+{[^}]+}' % _word, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)             
    res = re.findall(regex,filestr)

Comment: @NoamD: You might want to accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped you (the green tick on the left).